# Error in inserting nodes in red black trees

Tags: c, insertion, red-black-tree

I am trying to insert nodes in red black trees. The functions rotate_left, rotate_right, insertion are correct but rb_fixup seems to be wrong. The red color is shown as 1 and black as 0. I have implemented algo from CLRS. When third element is inserted it gives a segmentation fault.  The code of rb_fixup is:

```
struct node
{
    int data;

    int color;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *parent;
}*root;


rb_fixup(struct node *z)
{

    struct node *y;
    y=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    while(z->parent->color==1)
    {
        if(z->parent==z->parent->parent->left)
        {
            y=z->parent->parent->right;
            if(y->color==1)
            {
                z->parent->color=0;
                y->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                z=z->parent->parent;
            }
            else if(z==z->parent->right)
            {
                z=z->parent;
                rotate_left(z);
            }
            z->parent->color=0;
            z->parent->parent->color=1;
            rotate_right(z->parent->parent);

        }
        else if(z->parent==z->parent->parent->right)
        {
            y=z->parent->parent->left;
            if(y->color==1)
            {
                z->parent->color=0;
                y->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                z=z->parent->parent;
            }
            else if(z->parent->left==z)
            {
                z=z->parent;
                rotate_right(z);
            }
            z->parent->color=0;
            z->parent->parent->color=1;
            rotate_left(z->parent->parent);
        }
    }
    root->color=0;
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes a lot of pointers aren't null.  Add assertions to ensure that they aren't null.  For example, `while(z->parent->color==1)` assumes that `z` is not null and `z->parent` is not null.  You can add `assert(z != 0 && z->parent != 0);` before the loop to protect the first iteration; you'd need to do a bit more to make sure subsequent iterations are safe.  Or use a debugger to find out which statement is causing the crash and check all the pointers involved in that statement.

Comment: I added the lines but no help. To debug I did add print statements after every if/while to know where it might be having problems. If I enter the data 4, 41, 14, it shows me the print statements of after while, after else if( `else if(z->parent==z->parent->parent->right`) ) but then shows segmentation fault. So the problem might be in the lines :                                                                         `z=z->parent;`                                                                         `rotate_right(z);` @Johnathan

Comment: So, have you run the program with the debugger?  Which line is it crashing on?  Have you run it under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/)?  Does it tell you where the problem is?  Are there any problems before the crash?  How can we test your code without a sample of the RB-tree that you've created with the other functions?  How do you know that the rotate and insert functions are OK?  When do you call `rb_fixup()`, and why?  Have you got a function that dumps the entire RB-tree?  If not, go ahead and make one and use it.  If so, what does it say about the tree before you crash?

Comment: I ran the code with valgrind and I have solved the error. Thank You for the help :) @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Well done on solving the problem with just pointers to tools that can help you. May I suggest that you delete this question. If you don't want to lose the points from the up-vote, then you should post an answer with a summary of the changes you made to the code (and the fixed code). However, if the problem was in code you didn't show (or there were also problems in the code you didn't show), then either show that code too or delete the question after all. If the question and answer don't help other people, it shouldn't be on SO, and simply pointing to Valgrind and/or a debugger is not enough.

Comment: I have added the correct code!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem. The error with the above code is that it if the uncle is red, it does color the uncle and parent black and the grandparent red but it then goes down to do the operations written after `else if` of each condition and many conditions were not done correctly. The final code looks like the following:-

```
rb_fixup(struct node *z)
{

    struct node *y;
    y=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    while(z->parent->color==1 && z->parent!=NULL)
    {
        if(z->parent==z->parent->parent->left)
        {
            if(z->parent->parent->right!=NULL)
            y=z->parent->parent->right;
            if(y->color==1)
            {
                z->parent->color=0;
                y->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                z=z->parent->parent;
            }
            else if(z==z->parent->right)
            {
                z=z->parent;
                rotate_left(z,z->right);
                z->parent->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                rotate_right(z->parent->parent,z->parent);
            }
            else
            {
                z->parent->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                rotate_right(z->parent->parent,z->parent);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if(z->parent->parent->left!=NULL)
            {
                y=z->parent->parent->left;
            }           
            if(y->color==1)
            {
                z->parent->color=0;
                y->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                z=z->parent->parent;                
            }
            else if(z==z->parent->left)
            {
                z=z->parent;
                rotate_right(z,z->left);
                z->parent->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                rotate_left(z->parent->parent,z->parent);
            }
            else
            {
                z->parent->color=0;
                z->parent->parent->color=1;
                rotate_left(z->parent->parent,z->parent);
            }
        }
    }
    root->color=0;
}
```